# How Do I Build JAssimp With MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw

I'm using MinGW to try to build [JAssimp.](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/tree/master/port/jassimp)

For Unix users, the command to build the .so file is this:

```
gcc jassimp.cpp -I/usr/lib/jvm/default/include/ \
      -I/usr/lib/jvm/default/include/linux -lassimp -shared -fPIC -o libjassimp.so
```

However, I'm on Windows, using MinGW.

I've tried using this command to build the .dll:

```
gcc jassimp.cpp -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/ -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/win32 -lassimp -shared
```

Where `$JAVA_HOME$` is the path environment variable leading to the JDK directory.

However, I get this error when I try this:

```
In file included from jassimp.cpp:1:0:
jassimp.h:2:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you typing that `gcc` command into a `cmd.exe` window, or batch file or are you using some other shell or a makefile?  `cmd.exe` doesn't expand environment variables using the `$(xxx)` syntax, so if you're typing that into `cmd.exe` you should try `gcc jassimp.cpp -I%JAVA_HOME%/include/ -I%JAVA_HOME%/include/win32 -lassimp -shared`